# Pycharm project interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having trouble configuring a python interpreter for my project.
It was working great a few days ago and all of the sudden I can't configure anything for any project. I'm doing it the exact same way I did it before when it worked and its not working. Every time I try to configure a project interpreter, it gives me a red flag at the bottom and says: Cannot save settings: Please specify a different SDK name.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried setting a virtual environment and that doesn't work either. I know its probably something stupid.

Comment: In it's current form, I feel this question is lacking information. Could you please consider showing us a screenshot of the error, your current settings, or anything else that you think may help us help you?

Comment: Try change the setting by re-launching your PyCharm as Administrator.

Comment: Wait...it still doesn't work...

Comment: I cant explain this. Its really really strange...It decided to work for no reason after the 10th try of doing the EXACT-SAME thing! I must have a virus or some ghost on my computer.

Comment: Doesn't Pycharm work on Linux? I am just about to ditch windows.

Comment: SDK sounds almost like JavaSDK and PyCharm is written  in Java

Comment: maybe add screenshot to question.

Comment: SDK is an acronym for Software Development Kit and Java is one. Could you say any bundle of software that helps you develop is an SDK? It started working again for no apparent reason so I won't bother to upload a picture.

Comment: same here. couldnot find a way out. everytime I need to change sth on interpreter I am recreating a new project and moving source files into the new one.

Comment: here is a screenshot/gif: https://giphy.com/gifs/pycharm-error-xT0xez2b3TaCDLoloc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring interpreter in PyCharm: "please use a different SDK name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932725/configuring-interpreter-in-pycharm-please-use-a-different-sdk-name)

Comment: I definitely understand your frustration. In order to help, we need some more details. Can you show screenshots of how you set up your interpreter for a project? Or at the very least describe the steps in words. Then show us what error you are getting. We can try to help you better from tehre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find out the directory used by PyCharm to store settings, caches, plugins and logs for your OS from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).

Then try to find a file named `jdk.table.xml` within the sub-directories & delete it.

For me, it was `~/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/options/jdk.table.xml` in Manjaro.

Comment: I solved this quite a while ago with your solution and forgot to check mark your comment. Thanks.

Comment: As of 2023, one can also *Export settings*, *edit* the file however they see fit (not necessarily delete) and then re-import it. My PyCharm instance somehow persisted on using a deleted virtualenv as the default for new projects until I removed the corresponding `<jdk>` element (as well as a bunch of other potentially problematic ones).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to virtual environments having the same name

See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000792670--solved-Project-Interpreter-Error-Please-Specify-a-different-SDK-Name

Comment: Yeah I knew about this. It didn't matter what I named it. It wasn't saving settings.

Answer (score 0):

For `PyCharm2023.1` on Linux the solution is to navigate to `~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/options/jdk.table.xml` and manually remove the invalid interpreters. Each interpreter is enclosed into a `<jdk>...</jdk>` block.

A list of all the invalid interpreters can be found by navigating to `Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Console->Python Console` and checking the list that appears next to `Python Interpreter`. The invalid interpreters appear with a red color and a corresponding invalid statement.