# PyCharm couldn't add existing virtualenv

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment and I'm trying to add it in the project interpreter, but it keeps showing this error message below:

[image]

Why?
(the virtual environment has no problem)

Comment: [This has been asked already quite recently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862363/pycharm-project-interpreter)

Comment: Could you please share the link to the question?

Comment: My comment was the link to the question :-) They describe the same problem, but there isn't an answer yet though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring interpreter in PyCharm: "please use a different SDK name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932725/configuring-interpreter-in-pycharm-please-use-a-different-sdk-name)