# Configuring interpreter in PyCharm: "please use a different SDK name"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have been using Pycharm for years and have never had any problem.  However, after my most recent PyCharm update I can no longer configure the interpreter.

Also each time I create a new project it creates a vent directory under my project.  When I go to `File/Default Settings/Project Interpreter`, I am provided with new options.

In this window it allows you to configure a virtual environment, the conda environment, and the system interpreter.  I am assuming that I should configure the system interpreter.  From there I point PyCharm to the interpreter on my Mac at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3` and hit `OK`.

It then takes me back to the main window where it shows the path in the project interpreter. At this point I hit apply and get a message:

> Cannot Save Settings please use a different SDK name

It doesn't matter which interpreter I choose, I get the same message. Has anyone else come up with the same problem and how do I fix this?

Interestingly my old projects still work correctly.

Comment: related: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000792670

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon; I too noticed the difference in the latest version of PyCharm. It seems that it now has an affinity for the latest tool 'venv'. When you create an interpreter - that is what you get.

You can still create a virtualenv manually and point it there instead. I haven't looked into pointing it to a base python-bin because (frankly) you shouldn't generally do it.

My advice (and my proposed answer) is to embrace the change and let it create a 'venv' for you. From there, do all of your installs by "alt-F12". That will open a console with your virtual environment activate -- so your PIP installs into the virtual environment.

Once I began using virtual environments, I never looked back. It has made life much easier in the python world. Pycharm seems to know this as well and is trying to really encourage you to do the right thing.

SteveJ

[Edit Alternate way to get to terminal]

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the Mac equivalent of alt-F12 would you?

Comment: It is a pycharm shortcut not an OS one, so I hope it should work in both. However, you can get there from 'view->Tool Windows->Terminal'

Comment: Are they doing this so that you only install relevant packages, such that it is easier to import the code to a user without forcing them to install a full distribution?

Comment: That is part of it, but it is beneficial even if you never give your code away. It sandboxes your pip installations so that you don't have version dependency conflicts (if you are asking about virtual environments in general). You can look up why the switch to 'venv' from 'virtualenv' on the web, there is lots out there. I like the venv better personally because it is easier to ship with my code.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem while setting up the virtual environment for my project and no matter if I create a new virtual environment or select an existing one, I get the warning:

> "Cannot Save Settings please use a different SDK name"

Finally I found the solution:

Click on the **project interpreter** dropdown and select **show all...**. There you might be having multiple virtual environments with same name. Now here is the conflict you need to fix manually by renaming them so every item has the unique name.

Comment: Removing old unused venvs helped

Comment: Holy cow this was a frustrating error to track down. The PyCharm messages did not help at all, but this answer did the trick.

Comment: Delete/Edit ALL venvs with duplicate names. Even other duplicate venvs that have nothing to do with the current interpreter can cause this problem

Comment: I had this error even though I had no other venv in the list. My issue was with a duplicate JDK. Intellij on MacOS. The message is very unhelpful.

Comment: I had to resize the window... there were like ~15 Interpreters on the list, but none was visible until I resized the "Python Interpreters" window.

Comment: If you have multiple interpreters with the same name, you'll have to remove all of instances of the duplicates before you'll be able to remove any other interpreters. I had the issue where I tried to remove one duplicate to fix the issue, but PyCharm prevented me from clicking "apply" because (unbeknownst to be) there was another duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

How fix this in Windows 10:

1. close Pycharm .
2. delete this file: `C:\Users\<username>\.PyCharmCE2018.3\config\options\jdk.table.xml`
3. open Pycahrm again and load all python interceptors again.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. None of the other suggestions worked. I'm on Linux, so I had to delete ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.2/options/jdk.table.xml

Comment: for me that file was under `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/`

Comment: In my case on Windows 10 I've found it in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\options\jdk.table.xml`. I didn't delete the file, just removed the dead record, which was occupying the interpreter name I wanted to use.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue when trying to get **docker** up and running with Pycharm 2018.1 and using the container's Interpreter. I would get the error below.

> "Cannot Save Settings please use a different SDK name"

The issue I had was due to having multiple python interpreters **of the same name.**

Under **Pycharm || Preferences || Project Interpreter**

Click "show all" within the Project Interpreter dropdown and then delete any / all interpreters that you don't need.

Comment: This has also been mentioned in [JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000792670--solved-Project-Interpreter-Error-Please-Specify-a-different-SDK-Name) by [Craigmjackson](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/profiles/1541711410-Craigmjackson)

Answer (score 4):

This may be a known issue of PyCharm and using the method of the accepted answer may not resolve it. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27251.

You can close Pycharm and remove `jdk.table.xml` file from  `~/Library/Preferences/.PyCharm2018.1/options` directory (Mac version), then start PyCharm again.

Warning: By doing this, all your existing setup of python interpreters will be erased and you need to re-setup them again.

Comment: You can delete the whole directory to start over without the problems.  ~/Library/Preferences/.PyCharm20*

Comment: This one here solved the problem for me in PyCharm 2019.2 when nothing else did.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error:

1. I deleted all invalid project interpreters ( they are red)
2. then I did https://stackoverflow.com/a/60583928/3842788

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 or more virtual environments with same name. Even if you have projects with same name stored at 2 different places, please give unique name to its venv. This will solve your problem.

To check all the virtual environments:
Go to **File >> Settings >> Project: your_project_name >> Project Interpreter**

And rename the venv name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I moved my project to a different location and PyCharm started complaining about `Cannot Save Settings please use a different SDK name`. At the top of the main editor, it asks me to `Configure Project Interpreter`. I clicked it, and then ...

My solution

1. Remove all existing interpreters that are marked as invalid in the preference.
2. Select the interpreter in the moved `venv` subfolder in my project.

Without doing both, I kept getting the same "SDK name" error. It seemed that the project thinks that it already has an interpreter called "python.exe", if you don't actively remove all "invalid" ones.

Comment: To clarify: under `Settings`->`Project:...`->`Python interpreter`, select `Show all` from the dropdown to bring up the "Python interpreters" dialog, then delete the ones marked `[invalid]` in the list. Make sure to disable the filter "Hide virtual environments associated with other projects" (the funnel icon at the top), to show the full list.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project > Project Interpreter > Select the dropdown menu > "Show All".

For me, there were several Python environments, two of which were red with an  tag. Remove the envs that are red / have an  tag, select the remaining valid one, and re-apply settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by cleaning the Pycharm memory cache

[image]