# Why is pyCharm print error "Please specify a different SDK name" when I deleted all other environments?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

pyCharm keeps on printing out "Please specify a different SDK name" when trying to create a new conda environment or any other environment. I followed one of the solution and I did show all, removed all duplicated environments and added my new environment but still it gives the same error. Anyone knows what could be the issue?

I also tried creating new environments from the terminal instead and activating them. But again when I try and add them it either gives the same error or best scenario it builds the environment but then I get "Invalid python interpreter"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring interpreter in PyCharm: "please use a different SDK name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932725/configuring-interpreter-in-pycharm-please-use-a-different-sdk-name)