# PyCharm does not recognize the interpreter it just created

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

## Problem Statement

My PyCharm project does not recognize any Virtualenv project interpreter, including ones it successfully creates.

## Steps Taken to Produce Error

1. I opened PyCharm to the Welcome to PyCharm window.
2. I clicked `Get from Version Control`. I cloned a private repo from my GitHub into my local system. I confirmed that all files from the repo were present.
3. I opened the `Add Python Interpreter` window via `File -> Settings -> Project: myProject -> Project Interpreter -> (gear button) -> "Add..."`.
4. I selected the `Virtualenv Environment` option and the `New environment` radio button. I confirmed that the target Location `(...\myProject\venv)` did not yet exist. I selected Python 3.7 as my base interpreter, an installation which I have used without issue in other projects. I left both `Inherit global site-packages` and `Make available to all projects` unchecked.
5. **PyCharm successfully created the Virtualenv.** I confirmed this in both PyCharm's Project tab and Windows Explorer. Double-clicking `...\myProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe` launched a Python 3.7 shell as expected.

However, PyCharm's infobar at the bottom of the main window said `<No interpreter>`. The Project Interpreter settings menu also said `<No interpreter>`, and upon expanding the interpreter list dropdown, **the interpreter which PyCharm had just successfully created for myProject was not listed.**

#### Note

After taking the above steps, the newly-created Virtualenv is listed as an option under the `Existing Interpreter` radio button. However, selecting this option does nothing; the Project Interpreter window still says `<No interpreter>`.

## Failed Remedies

- Closing and Reopening PyCharm.
- Choosing the `Existing Interpreter` radio button and targeting `myProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe`.
- Choosing the `Existing Interpreter` radio button and targeting the `python.exe` in a different project's Virtualenv.
- Restarting my computer then `Existing Interpreter -> myProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe`.
- Creating a second Virtualenv `(myProject\venv-2)`.
- Deleting all existing Virtualenvs, then creating a new one in `myProject\venv`.

## Leads

Creating a new, separate project `(myProject_2)` using the exact same steps as above does NOT replicate the error; a new Virtualenv is successfully created and recognized. **This error is unique to `myProject`.**

Regardless, I'm going to leave this question up. I want to understand what's going wrong here.

```
[Project Directory Structure]
myProject
    assets
        css
        images
        js
    MyProject
    courses
        migrations
        templates
            courses
        templatetags
    templates
    users
        migrations
        templates
            users
        templatetags
    venv


[Info]
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
PyCharm 2019.3.3
Python 3.7.7
```

Comment: Please note the popup text for the [tag:git] and [tag:github] tags, which point out that you should not use these tags simply because the operation involves a Git repository on GitHub.

Comment: @torek Ah, okay. Thank you for removing them for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077693/10134974) to a related question—where the error message "Please specify a different SDK name" is being raised—about PyCharm interpreters may be what you are looking for.

I also had an issue with interpreters not loading, and it turned out to be an underlying conflict, which PyCharm was not giving me any helpful error messages about. The issue wasn't resolved until I deleted the `jdk.table.xml` file, which for me (on Mac OS) was located here: `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.2/options`.

Comment: OMG, thank you that worked on macos after updating to Sonoma.